# Link contact to Twitter handle

Tags: contacts, twitter

Is there something I can put into the Google Contacts entry for someone that will link it to their Twitter handle? I have tried putting “@JohnDoe” into an IM-type field I’ve named Twitter, but that didn’t do the trick.

Comment: To clarify, you want to be able to view a contact and click something to go to their Twitter page?  Have you tried a hyperlink?  Or syncing your Twitter contacts?

Comment: I was hoping for something that would link to the twitter app; and yes, I (think) I’m syncing my Twitter contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Facebook and Twitter contact sync stopped doing anything useful sometime recently (ICS?). They no longer provide a meaningful between your phone contacts and the actions provided by those clients. I think this has to do with changes to the Android API that for whatever reason these companies have not adapted to.

There is a stop-gap solution for Facebook using a third party app such as [Contact Sync for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.weednet.contactssync&feature=search_result) or [Friends Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.watto.program.android.sync.facebook&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwib3JnLndhdHRvLnByb2dyYW0uYW5kcm9pZC5zeW5jLmZhY2Vib29rIl0.)* but I don't know any solution for Twitter other than the hack-it method of having a URL listed and using the web client.

* This publisher also has [other sync apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=WATTO+Studios) for foursquare, flickr, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Ad in Google contacts a field for a website.
If your lad has the twittername @abc, enter
http://twitter.com/abc

On my Android phone it opens with my twitterclient, on the PC it opens the browser.